# Python: Circular import members from module

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

Suppose I have the following code.

```
foo.py
------
import bar
def abc(n):
    return bar.xyz(n-1) if n>0 else "abc"

bar.py
------
import foo
def xyz(n):
    return foo.abc(n-1) if n>0 else "xyz"
```

As explained in this post [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python), it will work. (The short explanation is, suppose we call `import foo` from python repl, when `import bar` is first encountered, python puts `bar` into `sys.modules` and executes `bar.py`, and when `import foo` is encountered, since `foo` is already in `sys.modules`, the import statement directly returns even though `foo` module is incomplete.)

Now if I change the code into the following:

```
foo.py
------
from bar import xyz
def abc(n):
    return xyz(n-1) if n>0 else "abc"

bar.py
------
from foo import abc
def xyz(n):
    return abc(n-1) if n>0 else "xyz"
```

The import will fail:

```
$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bar import xyz
  File "/Users/yxiong/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import abc
  File "/Users/yxiong/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bar import xyz
ImportError: cannot import name xyz
```

What is worth noting here is python seems to fail on the second try of `from bar import xyz`.

My question is, what is exactly going on at those steps. Specifically, what does python do when it sees a `from foo import abc` statement?

Comment: Plus one for the interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the frames, first Python attempts to load/compile the `foo` module (to be known as `__main__`, only compiles it once, but will be executed twice):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module> 
    from bar import xyz # first attempt to import xyx, but it depends on abc
```

Python attempts to execute the import statement.
So since Python only loads/compiles modules once (unless using `reload`), it looks in `sys.modules` and since it isn't there, it attempts to load/compile the `bar` module to import `xyz`.

```
  File "/Users/yxiong/bar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import abc # so we attempt to import abc, but it depends on xyz
```

But `bar` attempts to load/compile `foo` and import `abc`, which we see is already in `sys.modules`. And we're back to our original import:

```
  File "/Users/yxiong/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bar import xyz
```

and we get the ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name xyz
```

---

Let's empirically demonstrate, from a terminal in Unix:

```
cat > foo.py
print('executing ' + __name__)
from bar import xyz
def abc(n):
    return xyz(n-1) if n>0 else "abc"
```

<kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>

```
cat > bar.py
print('executing ' + __name__)
from foo import abc
def xyz(n):
    return abc(n-1) if n>0 else "xyz"
```

<kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>

```
python foo.py
```

Next experiment:

```
cat > main.py
print('executing ' + __name__)
import foo
```

<kbd>ctrl-d</kbd>

```
python main.py
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I did another experiment: run the `import foo` from python repl, and this time it fails at `cannot import name abc` (one frame fewer than running `python foo.py` from command line). As you explained, when running in command line, `foo.py` is first run as `__main__` module, and that is why python tries again for `import foo` when encountered at `bar.py` -- the `foo` is **not** in `sys.modules` yet. On the other hand, if run from repl, the `foo` is in `sys.modules` and therefore python claims failure without trying to `import` it again.

Comment: Edited to clarify, as I intended to inform that it is only imported once.

Comment: Actually I don't agree. If I add `print __file__, __name__` to both files, and run `python foo.py` from command line, I got 3 prints: `foo.py __main__`, `bar.py bar` and `foo.py foo`; if run from repl, only 2 prints `foo.py foo` and `bar.py bar`. This means when run in command line, `foo` is indeed imported twice, the first time as `__main__` and second time as `foo`.

Comment: As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python), "the executing script runs in a module named `__main__`, importing the script under its own name will create a new module unrelated to `__main__`."